# Conjectured closed form of $\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1+x)\,\ln^3x}x\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, integration, special-functions

I posted this question on Math Stack Exchange, but there were no helpful comments or answers
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4874446/1298448

How to integrate $${\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1+x)\,\ln^3x}x\mathrm{d}x}$$

### My idea

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^3 (1+x) \ln^3 x}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x &= -18 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( -1 \right )^{n+1} \left ( \mathcal{H}_{n+1}^2 - \mathcal{H}_{n+1}^{(2)} \right ) \frac{1}{\left (n+2  \right )^4}  \\
&= 18 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left ( \mathcal{H}_{n+1}^2 - \mathcal{H}_{n+1}^{(2)} \right ) \frac{1}{\left ( n+2 \right )^4} \\
&= 18 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \left ( \mathcal{H}_{n}^2 -  \mathcal{H}_{n+1}^{(2)} \right ) \frac{1}{\left ( n+1 \right )^4}
\end{align*}

Mariusz Iwaniuk give the closed form using symbolic calculator
Solution by MultiPolylog:
$$36MultiPolylog({5,1,1},{−1,1,1})$$

Comment: you can alternatively write the sums as ${\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1+x)\,\ln^3x}x\mathrm{d}x}=36\,\zeta(-5,1,1)$ --- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_zeta_function

Comment: @CarloBeenakker this is alternate form of the sums, I want to know how to evaluate last Euler sum

Comment: you are hoping for a closed-form expression for this multiple zeta function? that seems unlikely...